# Oracle9i export error

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

When I rut the following:

```
set ORACLE_SID=orcl
exp.exe 'SYS/system as sysdba' full=y log=exp.log  file=mydump.dmp
```

in the end i see the following:

```
EXP-00056: ORACLE error 942 encountered

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

what should i do to resolve it?

I had 9.2.0.1.0 oracle, after it was installed 2 patches: 9.2.0.7.0 and 9.2.0.8.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your export statement is valid but I have seen this when trying to mix/match export/import versions and databases.

Are you using the export binaries that go with the version of the database you are using? If you just type 'exp' it will tell you the version.

The version of your exp.exe should be the same as the database version you are trying to export. The exp.exe relies on structures in the database and these can change from release to release. So if your database is 9.2.0.8.0 then make sure you are using the exp.exe binary that is 9.2.0.8.0.

You may want to read [Using Different Releases and Versions of Export](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1012993) for more detail.

If you think your database and binarie may match and you still have problems then you may have had an issue when running catpatch scripts after your 9.2.0.8.0 patch.

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of views that must exist in order for import/export to run.

Run the following as the SYS user: /rdbms/admin/catexp.sql to create them.